# No module named unohelper

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

Django project, for generate pdf we use webodt. Transfer our VDS from Debian to Ubuntu and there are some problem: no module named unohelper
uno and unotools already pip install

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Libreoffice Version: 4.3.7
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
2.6.32-042stab108.2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

My guess is if your package is installed correctly, it is not found by `$PYTHONPATH`. Here are some steps to debug.
Run `pip freeze` from command line and check if your package is listed.
In a python shell run `import sys; sys.path`. This will list directories python looks in to find modules. The `dist-packages` directory should generally have any module installed using pip. [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471168/255529) might help you further debug your `$PYTHONPATH`.

(If you are using a python virtual environment, makesure you have activated your virtual environment, and `$PYTHONPATH` is able to locate your package)

Comment: result pip freeze: uno==0.3.3
unotools==0.3.3

Comment: @RinatBakiev So from django shell `python manage.py shell` if you run `import uno; uno` do you see the directory listed under `import sys; sys.path`? I have never used unohelper.. so not familiar if anything funky is happening with that particular package.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if you install uno via pip, you end up with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uno, which is a library of the same name but totally unrelated to LibreOffice.

According to this blog https://tmtlakmal.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/a-simple-python-macro-in-libreoffice-4-0/, what you need is to install Ubuntu (Debian) package called `libreoffice-script-provider-python` or possibly `python-uno` or `python3-uno` using apt-get.